# Chrome notifier for new Stack Exchange filtered questions

Tags: chrome, stack-exchange

I'm looking for a Chrome extension that will notify me (pop a desktop notification) when a new question is posted in any Stack Exchange site according to a Stack Exchange filter (as in http://stackexchange.com/filters).

There are dozens of Chrome extensions for Stack Exchange in Chrome Web Store but I can't find one that does that. Any ideas?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Any <s>RSS</s> feed extension should do the trick, as long as it supports Atom. I personally use [**Inoreader**](https://www.inoreader.com/), which comes with a [Chrome extension](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/inoreader-rss-news-and-so/hhglljfmpijadbpkalkclnhlncncdono?utm_source=chrome-ntp-icon).

What you need to do is subscribe to your filter(s) using the feed link at the bottom right of the page:
[image]

Then you can turn on and configure `desktop notifications` from Inoreader settings page, under the `behaviour`section:
[image]

Comment: Note that SE provides **Atom** feeds for filters, not RSS feeds, so the extension would have to support Atom (however, most extensions probably support all common feed formats anyway).

Comment: @unor True. The software still works, I just messed up the feed type. I'll fix the answer

Answer (score -1):

I've done a little research and it seems that such an application might be impossible at the time; The following two sources lead me to believe that the StackExchange was built to withstand malicious code (rightfully so,) and that in turn it disallows the use of the `window` object in Javascript. As a result it might not be possible to do this.

[Chrome desktop notification example?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2271156/chrome-desktop-notification-example)

[Browser notifications API doesn't work in Stack snippet](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/275029/browser-notifications-api-doesnt-work-in-stack-snippet)

Best of luck otherwise!